# Eclipse Java JTable vs Table

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, swt

For my company, I'm working on an Eclipse plugin which should do the following: show a table with sentences from the active editor that are incorrect in some way, accompanied by proper feedback. So far, so good.

However, sometimes the sentences/feedback are incorrect. I want a third column with checkboxes so that, when clicked, the related sentence/feedback combination is put in a different tab. Because I'm only programming in Java for 2 weeks now, I'm stuck: the plugin (written by my predecessor) is a class 'public class feedbackView extends ViewPart' using TabFolder and Table. But when I try to include checkboxes, all examples on the Internet use JTable. And I cannot get JTable to work in the current script and in the way I want (in Eclipse itself, instead of in a separate frame).

Ideally, I want [Example of feedbackView with TabFolder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yU5M.png). If in the 'Hide?' column the checkbox is checked, the sentence/feedback row should be transferred to the '||Hidden||' tab.

After this long introduction (hopefully clear), my questions:

- Can I use Tabfolder/Table for this? Or
- Should I use the JTable class (and how can I get this to work)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by table? is it a HTML table or a java.awt.Table

Comment: Given the list of imports, 'org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table'.

Comment: Your code is using SWT which is a different system from Swing. Although you can mix Swing with SWT it will look odd and is best avoided. SWT tables can have checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will start looking for SWT checkboxes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) is from Java Swing, with is the Java GUI component. Where [Eclipse Table](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FTable.html) is the an Eclipse GUI component. There are two different world, for building GUI's in Java.

**Warning:** You **can not** mix these two different Java GUI libraries!

Comment: Thanks! I was so confused that I thought that SWT and Swing were the same... Given that Eclipse Table is Eclipse-own, I suppose I keep using that one.

Comment: Actually you can mix SWT and Swing to a limited degree but it is best avoided.

Comment: Indeed, in case a Eclipse Plug-in is created, the SWT/JFace libraries should be used.

Comment: @greg-449 Indeed they can be mixed, but these are extreme rare cases. And should be avaided at any cost (as you already mentioned). Esp for a Eclipse Plug-in, as it would make things over complex. That's why I mentioned it as _can not_.